# Setting up an integral that represents the volume using Washer/Shell method

Tags: calculus, solid-of-revolution

Let A be the region in the first quadrant bounded by the curve $y=\cos x$, the line tangent to $y=\cos x$ when $x=\frac{\pi}{4}$ and the y-axis.

a) We now rotate A with respect to the line $y=-1$. Set up but do not evaluate the integral that represents the volume using cross sections.

b) We now rotate A with respect to the line $y=-1$. Set up but do not evalate the integral that represents the volume using cylindrical shells.

My work:

The line tangent to $y=\cos x$ is found by:

$y'=-\sin x$

$y'(\pi/4)=-\sin(\pi/4)=-\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}$

$y-\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}=-\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}(x-\frac{\pi}{4}$)

This is the equation of that line. The graph of this looks like:

[image]

**PART A**

For part a) is it asking to use the washer method?

The answer for part a) is

$$\pi\int_{0}^{\pi/4}(-\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}(x-\pi/4)+\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}+1)^2-(1+\cos x)^2 dx$$

I know that washers will be vertical and shells will be horizontal.

So for the washer method, the outer radius is

$R(y)=\cos x - (-1) = \cos x+1$

The inner radius is:

$r(y) = -\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}(x-\pi/4)+1$

So the volume is given by

$\pi \int_{0}^{\pi/4} (\cos x+1)^2 - (-\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}(x-\pi/4)+1)$

So I don't understand where I went wrong and why I get a different answer.

**PART B**

The answer is: $$\int_{a}^{b} 2\pi x(y) (y+1)dy+\int_{b}^{c} 2\pi(x(y)-\arccos y)(y+1)dy$$

where $a=\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}, b=1, c=\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}*\frac{\pi}{4}+\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}$ and $x(y)=-\frac{2}{\sqrt{2}}(y-\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2})+\frac{\pi}{4}$

I'm really confused about this second part. I don't understand the bounds of integration. I know that since I'm using the shell method, everything needs to be in terms of $y$ so $x(y)$ is the inverse tangent line.

But I'm confused about how to set this integral up and where each part comes from.

Comment: Well, for starters, look at your graph. Does that line look tangent to $\cos(x)$?

Comment: yeah that's what I was wondering too. It doesn't look tangenet to the graph, so is my equation of the tangent line incorrect? If so, where did I make a mistake

Comment: oh wait, is it because $\cos(\pi/4)=\sqrt{2}/2$? I used the point $(\pi/4,0)$ incorrectly?

Comment: okay, part (a) makes sense now, thank you very much. i'm still stuck on part b though. I updated the graph and the equation of the tangent line btw

Comment: The region bounded by the $y$-axis, $\cos$, and the tangent line only extends to $x = \pi/4$.